# « La miette », le « dérivé plaisant » de la mie de mon amie : détails ?

Tags: étymologie, linguistique, possessif, suffixes

(Ma) [*mie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mie/1) (et incidemment [*mamours*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mamours)) sont des vestiges, par mécoupure ou agglutination, de formes élidées de déterminants possessifs (*m'amie*, *m'amour* etc.) ; on parle généralement de la méprise de l'initiale *m'* qui réfère au possessif masculin ***m***'(on)amie, pour le féminin *ma* (TLFi). La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4157) en traite aussi et indique qu'on élidait par ailleurs des formes avec déterminant possessif féminin même avant le 12<sup>e</sup>, moment où on commence à employer le masculin pour éviter la double voyelle, et on a l'exemple *ma enfance/m'enfance*. Au DHLF on indique de plus que la forme masculine *m'ami* a complètement disparu et on atteste *mamie* en 1260 (aussi *m'amie*, *ma mie*) comme « terme appellatif de tendresse, puis d'affection », qu'on dit « sorti d'usage mais encore connu ». On ajoute :

> De *m'amie*, interprété en *ma mie*, est issue MIE n.f. (v. 1200) «
>   femme aimée », en général employé avec le possessif *ma* et devenu
>   littéraire (allusion au passé). Il a pour dérivé plaisant *miette* (1859
>   ; une fois *myette*, au XVIe s.).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed.
>   *Le Robert*, 2010, (ami, ie) ]

Ce *m'amie* n'est pas le terme appellatif de 1260, c'est simplement l'*amie* qu'on a. Le TLFi, lui, donne plutôt « maîtresse » (1567) comme [origine](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5766667f/f418.image) de la « femme aimée », si on comprend bien. Il va sans dire que tout ça n'a rien à voir avec la miette de pain.

---

- Un *dérivé plaisant*, qu'est-ce donc, est-ce la même chose qu'un [*hypocoristique*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocoristique) en linguistique, et un hypocoristique, est-ce seulement un emploi ponctuel ou est-ce un mot à part entière ; la *miette* est-elle ici un hypocoristique ?
- Quelle fonction de la suffixation en [*-(e)tte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ette) emploie-t-on dans
  le dérivé *miette* ? Est-ce que l'étymologie particulière, voire unique, de *mie* (*amie* à l'origine etc.) change comment la suffixation opère sur le
  sens ou l'emploi de *femme aimée*, le cas échéant, et quel en est le sens au final ; est-ce que c'est comparable à la dérivation de *fille/fillette* ?
- A-t-on un exemple clair, en littérature ou ailleurs, de ce dérivé *miette*, si possible autour de 1859 ?

Comment: Il me semble que _dérivé plaisant_ n'est pas un terme technique mais est simplement une allusion au fait que _miette_ est aussi utilisé (et plus couramment  au moins de nos jours) comme _petit morceau_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Merci, j'ai moi aussi l'impression que ce n'est pas un terme technique, mais je n'en suis pas certain et j'ai fait un lien sémantique entre _plaisant_ et l'intention caressante de l'hypocoristique. Cependant je ne comprends pas l'allusion au _petit morceau_ dont vous parlez, puisque nous sommes dans la vedette _ami,ie_ au DHLF (et non à l'entrée _mie_ (lat. mica)).

Answer (score 1):

*dérivé plaisant* est ici à prendre pour sa signification littérale : une dérivation du nom commun *"mie"* et qu'il est plaisant, puisque jugé mignon (petit).

On parle `d'une petite amie -> d'une petite mie -> d'une miette`.

> Quand mie, miche ont pris le sens général de « pain, mie de pain », il a fallu créer un diminutif, avec le suffixe -ette, pour le sens de « miette, tout petit bout de pain ». -[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/miette)(Étymologie)

---

> Il va sans dire que tout ça n'a rien à voir avec la miette de pain.

Pourquoi des homophones ne seraient pas employés de manière indifférente dans du vocabulaire familier + *affectueux*?

cf. : mon lapin (et plein d'autres) ... on parle bien de l'animal !